# Safe guarding against a duplicated test AD environment if it connects back to production

Tags: windows, active-directory

[This article](http://www.markc.me.uk/blog/files/DuplicatingAD.html) explains what a simple process it is to duplicate your AD setup to a test machine in an isolated network. The obvious issue is that if the isolated forest gets physically connected to production your screwed.

How can I safe guard against this? Is it possible to change the forest root domain name? Would that even be enough to prevent conflicts if it gets connected to production?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`The obvious issue is that if the isolated forest gets physically connected to production your screwed.`

Not simply because you connected it to your production network, but because it would have the same ip address as your production DC and the production domain clients would find it via DNS and attempt to communicate with it. All DC communication starts with DNS. A domain client finds a DC by querying DNS for the SRV records of a DC. If you were to change the ip address of the test Domain Controller then the production domain clients wouldn't find it and wouldn't attempt to communicate with it.

Now, I'm not saying it's a good idea to connect this duplicate DC to your production network even if you do change the ip address, I'm just clarifying that there's no "magic" going on under the hood. If the production clients can't find this DC via DNS then they can't communicate with it.

Comment: OK that clarifies it a little for me. So apart from keeping them on physically separate networks/subnets would changing the forest name be worth it (or possible)? Obviously like you say it should never been connected to the same network, but it the event that did happen and say someone who didn't know the environment changed the IP of a DC (unlikely) it would be an issue.

Comment: With a few exceptions, a domain rename is possible - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc781575(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There is a best practice from Microsoft Support when cloning a domain controller to prevent production corruption.  I am assuming a single DC in your test environment:

1. Open an administrative command prompt, reset the computer account password (TWICE) for the test Domain Controller:
   netdom resetpwd /server: /userD:Administrator /passwordD:*
2. If there are any Forest trusts, open an administrative command prompt to reset the trust password.  If there are no AD Trusts, then this can be skipped.  Keep in mind, for any child domains, this needs to be done to each child, and also from each child to the root.

   netdom trust  /domain: /resetOneSide /passwordT: /userO:administrator /passwordO:*
3. Use Active Directory Users and Computers, View Advanced, find the disabled krbtgt account (in the users container by default).  Re-set the password twice.  Use a complex password and uncheck the box “User must change password at next logon”.   A record of this password does not need to be recorded as the account is always disabled.   However, the password is used to derive Kerberos keys.

As stated by [joeqwerty](https://serverfault.com/users/19152/joeqwerty) be careful with the IP address.  In addition you need a DNS server on the test network servicing only test.  Make sure the DC is registering on that server and not production DNS.  You would also need to take into account WINS if in use.

Although we did not connect back to the production network, the above process was part of numerous steps when we performed a mock forest recovery. We now keep virtual machines on a private network in standby for an emergency recovery whenever we do risky AD changes.